# Update A MySQL Record With Specifies Values I Have

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, licensing

i am writing a licensing architecture and for the management purposes, i need to update the hardwareId, i have the generation and insertion script working but the update thing which updates it doesn't work

It is like when you purchase a product, your name and serial number is added to the database and it still has the hardwareID and activationID blank.

I want is that when the user activated the product, it updates the rows with the values like the serial 11111-11111-11111-11111-11111 and inserts the hardwareID say GHSHE-3FDFGDF-3R9WDJ-023

The script i have is not working:

```
<?php

//$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$serial = 'TF8NAIQI7ETF0EN9X8WF0V7YD';


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","clients","mypassword");
if (!$con)
{
die();
echo 'Error, In Connecting To Activation Servers';
}

$select =   mysql_select_db("my_database");


$resultGot =  mysql_query("UPDATE people SET hardwareID = 1111,  WHERE serialNumber =       '$serial';"  );
echo 'Done!';



?>
```

Comment: Spurious comma before the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove comma from your query.

And stop using mysql extention. It's deprecated. Have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).